# Is Bot Builder for multiple channels

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

I'm a bit confused on how Bot Builder is intended to be used if you want to connect to Slack as well as Kik.

Am I supposed to be using "builder.BotConnectorBot" or will I end up with a "builder.BotConnectorBot" and a separate "builder.SlackBot"? If so, does that mean I'm hosing two separate bots, one for Kik and one for Slack? Or can the same bot built using "builder.BotConnectorBot" be hosted once and work across every channel?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create a single bot.  Just enable it for multiple channels in the portal.

Direct link:
https://dev.botframework.com/bots?id={YourBotId}

Comment: Why is there a "builder.BotConnectorBot" and a "builder.SlackBot"? I imagine the "builder.SlackBot" can't be used to connect to a Kik channel. So then I would need to use "builder.BotConnectorBot" which leaves open the question when would "builder.SlackBot" be used? Seems like its not as simple as one bot, and I need to create two entirely different bots with there own paths.

Answer (score 0):

You develop one bot and you can use it across multiple channels (skype, slack, FB Messenger, Email, SMS, etc.). This is the main objective of BotFramework to abstract you to the channel implementations.

To add a new channel, you may enter in your bot and BotFramework dev portal and click in the channel you want to add. Some channels (like FB messenger and Slack) may require additional steps to setup the channel.

[image]

REF [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/channeldata/#navtitle).